# Running node process with sudo throws a syntax error

Tags: node.js, bash, ubuntu, syntax, ecmascript-6

Whenever I run my node app with the `sudo` command, it seems to throw an error on my Amazon EC2 instance (Ubuntu 16.04). But whenever I run it on the EC2 instance without `sudo` it runs normally. However I run it on my local machine (Mac Sierra OS), the app starts and functions normally.

I'm curious if anyone may have an idea why there's a SyntaxError being thrown, only when I use the `sudo` command on my remote EC2 instance.

I'm using node v.7.6.0 and npm v. 4.1.2 on both my local and remote machines, using NVM to manage versions on both too. Since the syntax error relates to ES2015 or 2016 syntax, I'm unsure why my local machine is able to interpret it properly while the Amazon EC2 instance (Ubuntu 16.04) isn't able to.

The error that I receive is shown below:

```
/var/www/mindmetrics/node_modules/twitter-crawler/lib/twitter-crawler.js:150
  api(method, ...params) {
              ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/mindmetrics/node_modules/twitter-crawler/index.js:20:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/mindmetrics/server/router/api.js:9:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at module.exports (/var/www/mindmetrics/server/router/index.js:6:20)
```

Answer (score 0):

My best bet would be that on your system, `root` has his own node.js executable, with a version that doesn't support the spread operator.

Try running `sudo node --version` and check if it is indeed v.7.6.0.

Comment: I think this is very likely since I'm using nvm to maintain versions of node